# How to change a variable from a nested function?

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire

When changing a variable inside a nested function scope it does not stay changed once the scope is left. In my example code when I set the variable xmlString equal to the response it correctly gets set to response. But then returns a empty string. 
`func getXmlString(url: String) -> String {
        var xmlString: String = ""
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .validate()
            .responseString { response in
                xmlString = response.result.value!
        }
        return xmlString
    }`

I know there is just a tiny thing I am missing and any help better understanding my situation would help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alamofire` is  acsynchonus. That why your xmlString empty. You should wait until you have a response from `Alamofire`.

```
 func getXmlString(url: String, completion: (xmlString: String) -> ()) {
            var xmlString: String = ""
            Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
                .validate()
                .responseString { response in
                    xmlString = response.result.value!

                 completion(xmlString)
             }
}
```

And use it

```
getXmlString(url: String){ xmlString in

//do something with your String
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to return the string value normally like I intended?.

Comment: `func getXmlString(url: String, completion: (xmlString: String) -> (String))`

Comment: use: `getXmlString(url){(xmlString) -> String in return xmlString}`

Comment: It's will return `the string value normally like you intended`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, however it returns "()" and not the string from the get request which is not what the response is.